# How to filter data from xml using xmldocument class & xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have xml stored in string variable. from that xml I need to filter data based on **StandardValue**. **I want to extract only those records whose StandardValue is not null & not empty**. I tried but my code did not work.

```cs
string xmldoc= @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitem>
  <Ticker />
  <TickerID />
  <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues>
    <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
      <TabName>Consensus Model</TabName>
      <StandardDate>1Q 2010</StandardDate>
      <BRTab>Income Statement</BRTab>
      <BRLineItem>NET REVENUES</BRLineItem>
      <Action>Extracted</Action>
      <StandardLineItem>Net Revenue</StandardLineItem>
      <StandardValue>329.623</StandardValue>
    </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
    <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
      <TabName>Consensus Model</TabName>
      <StandardDate>2Q 2010</StandardDate>
      <BRTab>Income Statement</BRTab>
      <BRLineItem>NET REVENUES</BRLineItem>
      <Action>Extracted</Action>
      <StandardLineItem>Net Revenue</StandardLineItem>
      <StandardValue></StandardValue>
    </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
    <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
      <TabName>Consensus Model</TabName>
      <StandardDate>2Q 2010</StandardDate>
      <BRTab>Income Statement</BRTab>
      <BRLineItem>NET REVENUES</BRLineItem>
      <Action>Extracted</Action>
      <StandardLineItem>Net Revenue</StandardLineItem>
      <StandardValue/>
    </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
  </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues>
</TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitem>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmldoc);
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue");
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
{
    foreach (XmlElement i in item)
    {
        if (i.Name == "StandardValue")
        {
            if (i.InnerText == string.Empty)
            {
                list.Add(item.OuterXml);
            }
        }
    }
}
string a = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in list)
{
    a = doc.InnerXml.Replace(item, "");
}

string str1 = doc.OuterXml;
```

My above code does not work. basically how to filter with **xpath** that return only those records **whose StandardValue is not null & not empty**.

How to achieve it with **XmlDocument class instead of xdocument.**

At end I have to stored filtered record's xml into string. I know **XmlDocument** class has outer xml property which return full xml.

Give me sample code which will return filter records & stored filter records xml into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input string your provided in the question.

This will select all TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue values that has StandardValue element and it's not empty or white space (`normalize-space`).

[normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space):

> strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces
>   sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the
>   resulting string.

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr); // <input from the question>

var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue[StandardValue and string-length(normalize-space(StandardValue))]");
```

Comment: please tell me the meaning of this `StandardValue and string-length(normalize-space(StandardValue))`

Comment: I updated my answer regarding the normalize-space. Generally in xPath: StandardValue (select non null) that has more than 0 length after normalizing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq which is the newer version of the Net xml library :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> tickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues = doc.Descendants("TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue")
                .Where(x => (x.Element("StandardValue") != null) && ((string)x.Element("StandardValue") != string.Empty))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to do it with xmldocument class... if possible please post answer with xmldocument. thanks